# When adding item to cart minicart doesnt show the subtotal

Tags: javascript, css, mini-cart

When I'm adding an item to the cart from product page it doesn't show the subtotal in minicart but when I reload the page it does. How to fix that? [Here is the link.](https://panoplie.com)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I saw JS issue in the console when loading your page, at the very first time visiting your site.

In JS, if error is not handled properly, it will cause the whole system to stop working properly

2. I tried to anyway and when adding to cart, it shows the same error. So this is the thing you need to fix
   [image]